# What is the meaning of the keystore validity in Android?

Tags: android, keystore, validity.js

Can be a sign to the expiration keystore, install are also available.

ex) 1 day keystore generate.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1
```

ex) my-release-key.keystore already is expired.

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

App launch is also available. So, What is the meaning of the keystore validity in Android?

Comment: a long time ago, when the app is installed with expired keystore (use to adb install *.apk, not app store), i think that the app can't also launch. so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**keystore** is used to validate developer's id,that is even the keystore has expired the application will work well on our android phone,it won't impress any functions about this app,but once the developer want to publish new version of this app,it can't use this keystore anymore,otherwise it will be refused by **Google play**,and if you use a new debug keystore to run on your device for debug,system will informs that pre app will be removed to install new one because they are not compat.

Comment: For a long time ago, i think that application can't launch when sign is expired. Is this policy changed?

Comment: @Charming,maybe,but I'm not sure,but now app will work well also even keystore has expired.

Answer (score 3):

this is from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

> If you plan to support upgrades for an app, ensure that your key has a
>   validity period that exceeds the expected lifespan of that app. A
>   validity period of 25 years or more is recommended. When your key's
>   validity period expires, users will no longer be able to seamlessly
>   upgrade to new versions of your application.
>
> If you plan to publish your apps on Google Play, the key you use to
>   sign these apps must have a validity period ending after 22 October
>   2033. Google Play enforces this requirement to ensure that users can seamlessly upgrade apps when new versions are available.

Comment: For a long time ago, i think that application can't launch when sign is expired. Is this policy changed?

Comment: if sign is expired You can't get any updates from play store

Answer (score 0):

> If you plan to support upgrades for an app, ensure that your key has a
>   validity period that exceeds the expected lifespan of that app. A
>   validity period of 25 years or more is recommended. When your key's
>   validity period expires, users will no longer be able to seamlessly
>   upgrade to new versions of your application.

Source: [Signing your application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Read more under section **Signing Considerations** to understand this better.

Comment: For a long time ago, i think that application can't launch when sign is expired. Is this policy changed?

Comment: It won't stop launching if already installed I think. But play store won't allow you to upload updates. This policy had always been there its not new.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But a long time ago, when the app is installed with expired keystore (use to adb install *.apk, not app store), i think that the app can't also launch. so...